# Make top bar of JFrame blend with the content pane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

How do I make the top bar of a `JFrame` blend with the content pane?

One of the things that makes Java applications look less native (at least to me) is the fact that the top bar of the JFrame is separated from the rest. Is there any way to replicate this in Java/Swing?

So, this (In finder):

[image]

Vs. this (`JFrame`):

[image]

Comment: There are probably platform-specific APIs to achieve that but not from pure Java code.

Comment: You might try putting a `JToolBar` into the title bar.

Comment: You cut off the frame-content border in the top picture.